# how i can introduce the localstorage in if's function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("countWon") === 5) {
    document.getElementById("game").style.display = "none";
    let right = document.getElementById("right");
    let won = document.createElement("h1");
    won.innerHTML = "You won!";
    won.style.color = "green";
    right.appendChild(won);
}
```

but it doesn't working, someone can help me?

Comment: Your value in localStorage will be a string "5". Comparing 5 === "5" will not be true.

Comment: Also ensure that you actually set/update `"countWon"` in your session storage. If you never actually set that data, the `if` will never be true. From what you've posted, it isn't clear if you've actually set the session storage in the first place. By the way, session storage is distinct from local storage.

Comment: IIRC, localStorage and sessionStorage both store items as strings, so your if condition will never be true, even if the stored value is 5, because `"5" !== 5`

Comment: Just wrap the 5 in quotes and it should work.

Comment: FWIW `if()` is not a function but a conditional statement ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1):

The `sessionStorage.getItem()` method returns a `string`

So you must compare the returned value with a string `"5"` or use the normal equality comparison operator `==` instead of the strict comparison operator `===` or you can convert the returned value to a number:

**Solution 1:**

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("countWon") == 5) { /* code here */ }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("countWon") === "5") { /* code here */ }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
if(Number(sessionStorage.getItem("countWon")) === 5) { /* code here */ }
```